# Django : Defining OneToMany Relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-related-manager

I am confused of defining `OneToMany` relation in django which is not in Django. `ManyToOne` field can be done using `ForeignKey`  but i dnt have idea to define for OneToMany.

here is my problem, I want to add Users as a list to a model.

```
Class Post(models.Model):
    postcontent =  models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    votedusers = ???  # list of users who voted
```

Simply it should lists the Users who voted a Post.
How to achieve this ?? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It should be the [many-to-many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) relation:

```
Class Post(models.Model):
    postcontent =  models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    votedusers = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Answer (score -2):

You cant see the docs here:
[Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

This is a example:

```
from django.db import models

class Reporter(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
    return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter)

def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
    return self.headline

class Meta:
    ordering = ('headline',)
```

In your case should be:

```
Class Post(models.Model):
    postcontent =  models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    votedusers = models.ForeignKey(Users)  # list of users who voted
```

Comment: The OP appears to be from India. Why would you answer this question in Spanish?

Comment: Can you translate this to English please?